# Find the specific cubic root that solves the constraint using binary search

Tags: c++11, binary-search

I am trying to find a cubic root(t) for the following equation, constraints

> F(t)=A(t^3)+B(t^2)+C*(t)+D, F(t)<=10^18.
>   Help find t such that F(t+1) > K, and F(t) <= K

I have tried the following approach;

What I did is followed binary search approach.Intially put t value as k/2 in the equation. If the result value is greater than k, I will try with t value k/4.Else if result less than k, I will check wit t value k/4. The program seems works with smaller values of k but the problem is the values exceeding the range for larger k. I guess I should pickup a better pivot value(intiall value) or change some equation

```
    int a,b,c,d;
    long long int k,x,y;
    long long int i,f,temp1;
    int def;

    def=0;
    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>k;
    i=1;
    f=k;
    temp1=(1+k)/2;
    while((temp1>=1)&&(temp1<=k))
    {
        x=a*(temp1+1)*(temp1+1)*(temp1+1)+b*(temp1+1)*(temp1+1)+c*(temp1+1)+d;
        y=a*(temp1)*(temp1)*(temp1)+b*temp1*temp1+c*temp1+d;
        if((x>k)&&(y<=k))
        {
            cout<<temp1<<endl;
            def=1;
            break;
    }
    else if(x<k)
    {
        i=temp1;
        temp1=(f+temp1)/2;

    }
    else if(x>k)
    {
        f=temp1;
        temp1=(i+temp1)/2;
    }

}
        if(def==0)
         cout<<def<<endl;
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think your solution will work here. I don't find any sense in applying binary search here.
I suggest newton's method to find the root of F(t)-K. And check which root satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Rishit my actually intention is to use binary search, rather than to solve the equation.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a chance of running into overflows, as the constraints of `a, b, c, d` are dynamic i.e they depend on the user.

But you can choose a better ending value for the range to search in while doing the binary search, but that might also have overflows if the values of a, b, c, d are large.

Also your binary search is too complicated, I have written a simpler binary search solution.

Note : That the overflows will occur if values of a, b, c, d are large, therefore you might wan to use a better ending range to search for the `t` value, in my example i have taken it as `1000000` i.e. cube root of k, because the other values are small.

code in c++ :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long a, b, c, d, k;

long long F_t(int val){
    long long ans = (a*val*val*val) + (b*val*val) + (c*val) + d;
    return ans;
}

bool check(int mid){
    if(F_t(mid) <= k) return true;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> k;
    long long st = 1, en = 1000000, ans = 0;
    while(st <= en){
        long long mid = (st+en)/2LL;
        if(check(mid) == true){
            ans = max(ans, mid);
            st = mid+1;
        }else{
            en = mid-1;
        }
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Demo on Ideone : http://ideone.com/4WlRuc

A big integer library may be helpful as it would eliminate the chances of an overflow and always provide the correct result using the above algorithm, where you can take the value of the endpoint of the range to be `k` (i.e `en = k`) and the complexity would be `O(log2(k))`.